# Instantiates a interface via deferred binding in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I am reading a code of `GWT`

Basically in this project they are getting some `constant` value like button text from a `properties file`.

so they have an interface `LocalizableResource` and getting the instance like

```
public interface LocalizableResource extends Constants {

 public static class Util {

            public static LocalizableResource getInstance() {

                    return  GWT.create(LocalizableResource.class);
            }
        }
   String lblName_text_1();
 }
```

and `use` this `instance` to get a button text

```
String buttonText = LocalizableResource.Util.getInstance().lblName_text_1();
Button b = new Button(buttonText);
```

`in java we can not Instantiates an interface then`,

How GWT doing this such like. I have not so much Idea about deferred binding and GWT.

Answer (score 0):

That's the beauty of GWT and one of its way to manage multiple clients which is  the core advantages of GWT framework.

> http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html
>
> Deferred binding is a feature of the GWT compiler that works by generating many versions of code at compile time, only one of which needs to be loaded by a particular client during bootstrapping at runtime. Each version is generated on a per browser basis, along with any other axis that your application defines or uses. For example, if you were to internationalize your application using GWT’s Internationalization module, the GWT compiler would generate various versions of your application per browser environment, such as “Firefox in English”, “Firefox in French”, “Internet Explorer in English”, etc… As a result, the deployed JavaScript code is compact and quicker to download than hand coded JavaScript, containing only the code and resources it needs for a particular browser environment.

Comment: LocalizableResource.Util.getInstance().lblName_text_1() in the following code how we get the definition of this function lblName_text_1()

Comment: how they are getting text from properties file. is there any configuration need

Answer (score 0):

> A tag interface that facilitates locale-sensitive, compile-time
>   binding of constant values supplied from properties files. Using
>   GWT.create(class) to "instantiate" an interface that extends Constants
>   returns an instance of an automatically generated subclass that is
>   implemented using values from a property file selected based on
>   locale. [more info](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Constants.html)